# VBA - copy the range in some cells and appear them into other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want a code that doing the following:
if the last 5 characters of the text value in the cell  in column E is “(UK)” then the macro copies the range consisting of 4 cells in columns B,C,D,E in the same row and pastes below the last non-empty row in the worksheet “Sheet 1” in the same columns (so all ranges B-E with “(UK)” must be transferred to the sheet “Sheet1”);

Comment: This is not a please code this for me site. This site is for fixing broken code. Please provide code that you have tried.

Comment: I feel like this question gets asked once a week XD

Comment: The following website might be able to get you started if you want to code it yourself: http://www.homeandlearn.org/. Otherwise, you can hire someone to code it for you here: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just posting my code. Hope @Jonathan will learn it.

```
Sub CopyC()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sheet1lastrow As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("sheet1")

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    sheet1lastrow = ws.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row



    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If Right(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value, 5) = "(UK)" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
            ws.Cells(sheet1lastrow + 1, 2).PasteSpecial xlValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Application.CutCopyMode = True
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```